# Как перенаправлять файлы по папкам в typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

можно ли сделать так, чтобы файлы ts были, напр, в папке TS, а js файлы которые генерируются после запуска ts файлов, попадали в JS каталог?..

почитала документацию ts, ничего подобного не нашла

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вам нужны параметры `rootDir` и `outDir` в конфиг файле (Файл `tsconfg.json`), поищите и почитайте про них.